# Arduino make GET request to Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, get, arduino

I'm trying to make a get request from a Arduino to Google App Engine:

```
client.println("GET /getData HTTP/1.0\r\n");
client.println("HOST: xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com\r\n");
client.println("\r\n");
```

And I get the following error message:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1576
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 12:07:34 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>Thatâ€™s an error.</ins>
  <p>The requested URL <code>/getData </code> was not found on this server.  <ins>Thatâ€™s all we know.</ins>
```

I cant seem to get the formatting of the request right. Does anyone have a idea how to get it working? When I test it against WAMP server everything works fine. Thanks

Comment: technically everything is working here. You send a request and you get a response, it's just not the response you expect. The error message cleary states that the particular resource cannot be found. Try to request that resource with a browser. If that doesn't work your appengine app either not working or not deployed at all. Also check the app engine logs for more information.

Comment: The request works with a browser, and if I try to access a invalid URL on my xxxxxxxx.appspot.com i get a different 404:

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Not Found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL <code>/getData2 </code> was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

Comment: You're getting the Google 404 page so it doesn't look like it's even hitting App Engine. What hostname is your `client` trying to connect to?

Comment: The hostname is xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com, the same as the HOST parameter in the request.

Comment: That url http://xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/getData (<- click it) certainly doesn't work / gives an 404 error (as expected).

Comment: There is no reason why it shouldn't work with the real app id. Communication is working fine, since you have received a 404 error already. You probably have a typo, invisible character or too many whitespace in the host name or the URI. I would try without the "\r"s.

Comment: When I remove the "\r" I get the following message:

HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 18:39:14 GMT

Comment: okay, different question: How do you open the socket and what dns/ip are you addressing?

Comment: My code is very similar to: 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

I ended up using a HttpClient instead, and it works great!
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
char server[]="your_server_name"; 
EthernetClient client;
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 40); // Arduino IP Add
IPAddress myDns(8,8,8,8);  // DNS 
IPAddress myGateway(192,168,1,1);  // your gateway

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
     Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
     // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
     Ethernet.begin(mac,ip,myDns,myGateway);
  }
}
```

in the loop():

```
... loop funcion
if (client.connect(server,80))  // Server port
{
  client.println("GET /getData HTTP/1.0\r\n");
  client.println("HOST: host_name\r\n");
  client.println("\r\n");
}
```